# memoir download

Tags: memoir, installing, miktex

I'm having trouble with the `memoir` template in LaTeX. Each time I build PDF with pdflatex, at the very beginning of the compilation it somehow tries to request something from the web, which isn't even necessary since after a a received timeout the PDF compiles just fine.

It's really disturbing my progress, since during writing I like to compile very often.

A further result of this `memoir` web request thing is that I get Forbidden from MiKTeX servers, after several compilation attempts.

Is there any possibility to suppress ANY web requests within pdflatex command?
Or what is the problem with `memoir`, that it web requests in each and every build although the required package (whatever it is?) seems to not exist on the MiKTeX repository?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You can turn of *automatic package installation* by using the `--disable-installer` switch. See the manuel: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texfeatures.html

Comment: Perhaps your local database is not in sync: go to the package manager and sychronize the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your local database is not in sync: go to the package manager and sychronize the repository.

Comment: If the MiKTeX `bin/` is in your `PATH`, this can be done with a simple [`mpm --update-db`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html).